# GeoPortal - "Not an XML response received from the host " when adding a resource using URL protocol

Tags: tomcat, geoportal, esri-geoportal-server

I have a local directory I want to connect to. It has been configured in IIS to list the contents. If I visit it in my browser, it displays the contents.

When adding it as a resource, it passes the connection test fine. However I get a red text error saying "Not an XML response received from the host" when I use the URL protocol (Which is the correct one I take it?)

I tried using the WAF protocol, it adds the folder as a resource, however it shows up as a single entry, and the metadata looks like it was generated on it's own.

See screenshot: [image]

The metadata it shows:

```
<rdf:RDF><rdf:Description rdf:about="http://localhost/MUNICIPAL/">
<dc:identifier>http://localhost/MUNICIPAL/</dc:identifier><dc:title>MUNICIPAL</dc:title>
<dct:references>http://localhost/MUNICIPAL/</dct:references></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF>
```

**My question:** How can I add a folder full of XML files to GeoPortal?

I am approving it after I add it.

EDIT: When I click preview, it shows this:

[image]

**EDIT**: Checked the gpt.xml log file. Seen an interesting error with web harvester:

```
Sep 8, 2014 2:53:45 PM com.esri.gpt.framework.context.ApplicationConfigurationLoader loadHarvesterConfiguration
INFO: [SYNCHRONIZER] Missing "webharvester.autoSelectFrequency" parameter. Default 3,600,000 will be used instead.
Sep 8, 2014 2:53:45 PM com.esri.gpt.framework.context.ApplicationConfigurationLoader loadHarvesterConfiguration
INFO: [SYNCHRONIZER] Missing "webharvester.watchDogFrequency" parameter. Default 60,000 will be used instead.
Sep 8, 2014 2:53:45 PM com.esri.gpt.framework.context.ApplicationConfigurationLoader loadHarvesterConfiguration
INFO: [SYNCHRONIZER] Missing "webharvester.baseContextPath" parameter. Harvest notification messages will be sent without information about harvest report.
Sep 8, 2014 2:53:45 PM com.esri.gpt.framework.context.ApplicationConfigurationLoader loadHarvesterConfiguration
INFO: [SYNCHRONIZER] Missing "webharvester.resource.autoApprove" parameter. Default false will be used instead.
```